# jaxb how can we pass a blank namespace

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

Below JAXB bean contains two namespaces one is "http://xyz/" and another is a blank namespace in NO1 and NO2. But the xml output does not specify the blank namespace. If I specify a value other than blank it works but for blank it does not. How can I pass a blank namespace to NO1?

```
package com.abhi.test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlRootElement(name ="errorData", namespace="http://xyz/")
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ErrorData 
{
    @XmlElement(name="NO1", namespace="")
    private String no1;
    @XmlElement(name="NO2", namespace="")
    private String no2;
    public String getNo1() {
        return no1;
    }
    public void setNo1(String no1) {
        this.no1 = no1;
    }
    public String getNo2() {
        return no2;
    }
    public void setNo2(String no2) {
        this.no2 = no2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = 
            JAXBContext.newInstance(ErrorData.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            ErrorData data = new ErrorData();
            data.setNo1("data1");
            data.setNo2("data2");
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output of above code is below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:errorData xmlns:ns2="http://xyz/"> 
    <NO1>data1</NO1>
    <NO2>data2</NO2>
</ns2:errorData>
```

However I am looking for below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:errorData xmlns:ns2="http://xyz/"> 
    <NO1 xmlns="">data1</NO1>
    <NO2 xmlns="">data2</NO2>
</ns2:errorData>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pass a namespace to NO1"? If your classes are correctly mapped, JAXB will manage namespaces for you. You should probably post a [MCVE].

Comment: I have updated the question and added an example to it. Thanks!

Comment: Your two XMLs are equivalent.

Comment: Do you explicitly want `xmlns=""` in the `NO1` and `NO2` elements? Why? That doesn't seem useful in any way, and only makes your XML more verbose.

Comment: @Jesper passing xmlns="" unsets the default namespace if any inherited from the parent.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?